# Cannot activate pyfinance in anaconda

Tags: anaconda, package

[Screenshot successful installation of pyfinance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQKJN.png)

Hello community,

I try to activate pyfinance through terminal but it tells me package is not available. Also, in Anaconda itself, I don't find it in the package base.

Before, it has asked me to remove seaborn, which I did. I then installed pyfinance, which was installed successully.

With "source activate pyfinance", it will give me an error message though.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

I know that you solved, but I would like to reply for the community.

You can solve this by typing this on the terminal/console

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge pyfinance
```

If the above didn't work save the following:

```
name: pyfinance channels:
 - defaults dependencies:
 - bleach=1.5.0=py36_0
 - cycler=0.10.0=py36_0
 - decorator=4.1.2=py36_0
 - entrypoints=0.2.3=py36_0
 - freetype=2.5.5=2
 - html5lib=0.999=py36_0
 - icu=54.1=0
 - inflection=0.3.1=py36_0
 - ipykernel=4.6.1=py36_0
 - ipython=6.1.0=py36_0
 - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py36_0
 - ipywidgets=6.0.0=py36_0
 - jedi=0.10.2=py36_2
 - jinja2=2.9.6=py36_0
 - jsonschema=2.6.0=py36_0
 - jupyter=1.0.0=py36_3
 - jupyter_client=5.1.0=py36_0
 - jupyter_console=5.1.0=py36_0
 - jupyter_core=4.3.0=py36_0
 - libpng=1.6.27=0
 - markupsafe=0.23=py36_2
 - matplotlib=2.0.2=np113py36_0
 - mistune=0.7.4=py36_0
 - mkl=2017.0.1=0
 - more-itertools=3.2.0=py36_0
 - nbconvert=5.2.1=py36_0
 - nbformat=4.3.0=py36_0
 - notebook=5.0.0=py36_0
 - numpy=1.13.1=py36_0
 - openssl=1.0.2l=0
 - pandas=0.20.3=py36_0
 - pandas-datareader=0.4.0=py36_0
 - pandocfilters=1.4.1=py36_0
 - path.py=10.3.1=py36_0
 - patsy=0.4.1=py36_0
 - pexpect=4.2.1=py36_0
 - pickleshare=0.7.4=py36_0
 - pip=9.0.1=py36_1
 - prompt_toolkit=1.0.14=py36_0
 - ptyprocess=0.5.1=py36_0
 - pygments=2.2.0=py36_0
 - pyparsing=2.1.4=py36_0
 - pyqt=5.6.0=py36_2
 - python=3.6.1=2
 - python-dateutil=2.6.0=py36_0
 - pytz=2017.2=py36_0
 - pyzmq=16.0.2=py36_0
 - qt=5.6.2=2
 - qtconsole=4.3.0=py36_0
 - quandl=3.1.0=py36_0
 - readline=6.2=2
 - requests=2.14.2=py36_0
 - requests-file=1.4.1=py36_0
 - requests-ftp=0.3.1=py36_0
 - scipy=0.19.1=np113py36_0
 - setuptools=27.2.0=py36_0
 - simplegeneric=0.8.1=py36_1
 - sip=4.18=py36_0
 - six=1.10.0=py36_0
 - sqlite=3.13.0=0
 - statsmodels=0.8.0=np113py36_0
 - terminado=0.6=py36_0
 - testpath=0.3.1=py36_0
 - tk=8.5.18=0
 - tornado=4.5.1=py36_0
 - traitlets=4.3.2=py36_0
 - wcwidth=0.1.7=py36_0
 - wheel=0.29.0=py36_0
 - widgetsnbextension=2.0.0=py36_0
 - xz=5.2.2=1
 - zlib=1.2.8=3
 - pip:
   - ipython-genutils==0.2.0
   - jupyter-client==5.1.0
   - jupyter-console==5.1.0
   - jupyter-core==4.3.0
   - prompt-toolkit==1.0.14 prefix: /Users/marci/anaconda/envs/pyfinance
```

as a file, example: **environment.yml** (on your desktop, under a Folder: **PythonForFinance**).

Once done open your terminal console, look for the path

```
$ cd PythonForFinance/*
```

then

```
$ cd PythonForFinance/ env create -f environment.yml*
```

Now type on windows console

```
$ source activate pyfinance
```